# MIPS pipelining and throughput

Tags: mips, throughput

I am learning to program using the MIPS instruction set architecture and since this architecture is designed for pipelining I have a few questions regarding pipelining and throughput.

I understood that throughput is the number of instructions per unit of time. 
How do you determine throughput for say 3 instructions having instruction fetch, decode, execute/address generation, memory operation and write back as the stages of execution.

Throughput as I understood is the maximum work that is processed in parallel when the pipeline is full for one clock cycle hence throughput should be 3. If the answer is 3 why is it that the slowest instruction determines throughput?

Answer (score 1):

*Throughput* is the number of instructions that complete in each clock cycle. For a non-superscalar machine, the throughput will be one instruction per clock cycle. In a RISC architecture like MIPS each instruction takes one cycle to execute, though memory references will usually take many cycles to read or write memory.